# How to convert .lit files in other formats?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, conversion, ebooks

I've changed my e-reader and i want to convert my .lit files in other supported formats (AZW, TXT, PDF, HTML, DOC, DOCX, JPEG, GIF, PNG or BMP)

thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Calibre** is what you are looking for! It can also handle your whole library.

- Search for it in the *Software Center* and install it.
- Then - once you started it - add your .lit files to the library.

Now you can convert your books into other formats, readable by your *new* e-reader:

1. First *select* a book in the list you want to convert and *click* on *Convert books*.
2. In the new window that pops open, you'll have multiple possibilities to the final resulting eBook.
3. The most important part though is the *output format* in the upper right corner - by default it is set to **EPUB** - *change* it to the needed format.

Play around with this little piece of software, try different settings, etc.

**This only works for non-DRM eBooks!**

Comment: But if your .lit files have Microsoft's DRM applied to them, you can't convert them in Calibre (or in any other tool).

Answer (score 1):

.LIT files are Microsoft Reader eBook files, and they are not as widely supported as some other eBook formats. If you want to convert.LIT files to other formats, you can follow these steps:

Use Calibre:

1. Download and install [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook) (a free open-source eBook
   management tool)
2. Open Calibre and click on "Add books" to import
   your    .LIT file.
3. Once added, select the book in Calibre's library
   and click "Convert books.

Use ebook-convert:

It's also possible to use the `ebook-convert` [command line tool](https://converra.com/converter/webp/png) to perform the conversion with a single command, allowing scriptin. Documentation for this is [available here]